# New to Ubuntu and I need some help

Tags: installation

Alright so I have a P.O.S. Toshiba laptop that's currently running Windows 7 OS. Things were great up until sometime last month it started crashing in the middle of work or just browsing. I'm quite fed up with Windows as well as Microsoft. I figured I could just erase Windows 7 and replace it with Ubuntu. Now I'm sure this can not be done but if it is possible please let me know.

If not, that's fine I could then just make a partition and running through that. But, here's the problem, I can't install it to make a either decision. I have a USB thumb drive that has Ubuntu 12.04 installer on it and it'll boot from that with no problem. I can even play around on it a bit. When I try to install it comes up with the 'Want to try' or 'Want to install', I click install.

From there it shows me the options 'Connect to internet' or 'Don't connect'. I click connect and get everything ready to go. When I click continue, I get the little pinwheel loading cursor and nothing else. It just stays like that for hours. I ran it for about four hours.

If anyone could please let me know if it may be a faulty USB drive, file, etc. 
My wife writes and she can't if Windows keeps crashing.

Open to any suggestions... Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Firstly I think you should try to choose the *Want to Try* option, then when it is loaded, hit the *Install* icon on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could, in both Windows and Ubuntu, be caused by a failing Hard Disk drive it may be worth scanning the disk in Windows to see how good the HDD is.

If  it has bad sectors, it may be worth your while to Google the cost of a new Drive and loading which ever version of Ubuntu you prefer.

Once you change to Ubuntu, you will not want anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar troubles installing ubuntu on people's machines. A common culprit is the internet. Disable wifi and disconnect all cables while installing. (Just choosing don't download updates is not enough sometimes.. it seems to try and get into trouble nevertheless.)